# How to train large datasets in Colab free

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, siamese-network

I have to train 70,000 images for my face verification project on google colab free.
First, it gets stuck on 1st epoch and then even if it starts training, after sometime it throws out of RAM error.
The code I use is:

```
<https://nbviewer.org/github/nicknochnack/FaceRecognition/blob/main/Facial%20Verification%20with%20a%20Siamese%20Network%20-%20Final.ipynb>
```

If I've to make mini-batches of my dataset to fit it in the colab's GPU memory, then how can I do it?
Also, I want to train the whole dataset because it contains the images of 5 different people as anchors and positives.

Comment: How are you loading the mini-batches? Please share some code. Are you trying to load all the 70,000 images at one in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following options to train larger datasets.

1. Add more pooling layers in model.
2. Lower input size in your model.
3. Use Binary Format of images with lower image size for image classification models.
4. Lower the batch size while training and validating your model.
5. You can also use [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data.) api to do various operations like  batching , slicing , processing, shuffling etc to create a data pipeline. You can constrain [GPU usage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth.) further to avoid Out of memory issues.

Attaching sample colab notebook below.    https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/data.ipynb